# Вывод температуры CPU

Tags: android

Подскажите, как в Android-приложении вывести температуру CPU?

Comment: Кури доку [вот][1]. а также [вот][2]


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6985579/2604639

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать  [TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE) для получения температуры батареи и процессора.  Пример.

```
    public class TempSensorActivity extends Activity, implements SensorEventListener {
 private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
 private final Sensor mTempSensor;

 public TempSensorActivity() {
     mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
     mTempSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
 }

 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mTempSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
 }

 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
 }

 public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
 }

 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Если виджетом, то можно [скачать это](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sanels.tempcpuv2&hl=ru). Если программа с подробными данными о CPU, то [эта](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yanyan.cputemp&hl=ru).

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?